# Why is iterating over a hashmap O(c/n)?

Tags: performance, hashmap

There are lots of links that tell me that the Big O for a hashmap is:

```
get   O(1)
add   O(1)
contains O(1)
next item O(c / n)    c = table capacity (number of buckets) n = size
```

It is kinda of obvious why get/ add / contains are O(1), but I want to know why the iteation is O (c / n).

And while I am at it, I love to know why the Big O's are what they are for ConcurrentHashmap, TreeMap etc.

Anyone got a good link?

Comment: What is your source for O(c/n)?  I never saw a BigO like that.  Iteration (going through the entire collection) is always O(n).

Comment: Source here: http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf

Comment: The linked paper *does not* say iteration is `O(h/n)`. It says *"next entry"* is `O(h/n)`. Iteration is "next entry" *for every* n.

Comment: @pst I will edit question. Sorry.  But can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked paper *does not* say iteration is `O(c/n)`. It says "next entry" is `O(c/n)`. Iteration is "next entry" for every n.

First off, note that `c (capacity) > n (entries)` is an invariant - and c is some function of n - so `O(c/n)` > `O(1/n)`. (Note: as per the comment, I'm not entirely certain about my assertion about the invariant in the HashMap implementation which uses chaining for collision resolution.)

So what this effectively says is that in a standard HashMap some buckets that are looked at while performing a "next entry" are *empty* and must be skipped. Thus the bounds are "more than" `O(1/n)` for "next entry". Care when reading this bounds, though, because it *does not* imply that iteration faster with more `n` - it just describes the "next entry" bounds in terms of the total `n` entries.

Since iteration is effectively just "next entry" for all n, for iteration of a HashMap:

```
O(1/n * n) -> O(n)
O(c/n * n) -> c*O(n) -> ~O(n)
```

(Since `c` is a function of `n` it *may* be a bit misleading in different situations to pull it out as a constant; hence the squiggle.)

Comment: Firstly, what is meant by "next entry" and why is capacity > entries. If you have 6 buckets and 18 entries than c < n ??

Comment: just going to dig a bit more about "next entry" - but it is not orderd. So does it mean to get the next element that would be in order if order was used? I agree it is O(N) for iteration. Just still confused about "next entry"?

Comment: @MoreThanFive "next entry" doesn't imply an order. Starting at the "first entry" and repeatedly calling "next entry" will eventually get to the "last entry" while only returning entries in the hash map and without ever repeating an entry.

Comment: well if that's what it is I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be c*O(n) as it effectively going c linked lists which means O(n). So I shall accept your answer.